# Opencart 3 category description visibility question

Tags: opencart, categories

I am running OC 3.0.2.0 and looking for a way to show category description only on the category first page and hide it on 1, 2, 3 pages and so on.

I have to edit the `category.twig` file, but I am not familiar with the syntax.

I have found some code but it is for older versions of OC.

Answer (score 0):

Open controller `\catalog\controller\product\category.php` and search code:

```
if ($category_info) {
   /* here code */
   ..........

   $data['page'] = $page; // adding this code

   $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data));
}
```

Open template `\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product`

Search:

```
{% if description %} 
  <div class="col-sm-10">{{ description }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Replace:

```
{% if description and page == 1  %} 
  <div class="col-sm-10">{{ description }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

**UPD for first part:**
Add this string

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't understant the first part, so i skipped directly to editing the \catalog\view\theme\default\template\product. The result was that the description was hidden on all category pages, event on the main one. My category main page is on the following URL: index.php?route=product/category&path=59

Comment: @seers007 I add screen. First part you need to make sure

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunatelly I tried again and the result is the same. The category text is hidden on every page, including the main one.